# User profile properties "Email Notifications" value interpretation

Tags: user-profile-property

I am creating an application for backups.

Most of the properties with multiple values didn't give me any problems, but "Email Notifications" type was integer (instead of string multiline). I was wondering how to interpret the property's value (e.g. when all checked -0, when first 2 checked - 4 and etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Email notifications values are mapped to the binary format made by checking , unchecking the 3 checkboxes in the property.All checked boxes are considered as 0 and unchecked boxes are considered as 1.

For eg: Suppose all the 3 boxes are checked then it would correspond to "000" which is binary format of 0 and hence returns 0. If first 2 are checked it would be "100" ie binary value of 4.

See this [blog](http://www.spnote.com/post/2013/04/09/Set-Email-Notification-values-on-a-UserProfile) which explains this in detail.